# Progammatically Save Order To Another Mage Install (local)

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, magento-1.9

We have two Magento installs 1.8, one for our live site and another for "other" development. Both are on the same server, different folders dbs etc, basically identical, they have the same products, setup etc.

What we are looking for is a solution to replicating orders from one Mage website to the other.

We want our live Magento site to also save customer orders to the "other" Magento as well as its own. Sort of programmatically creating the same order in the other Magento.

That way we see the same orders in both sites. The live site and the "other".

What is your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a master/slave DB set up with the slave of the server acting as the DB for your other website. My wild guess is that you are using the "other" website as a back end for order full fillment etc.